# Are these two URLs a type of query string? Need to determine if these two URLs are serving static data or dynamic

Tags: url, javascript, web, database, xml

I am attempting to solve a puzzle. My most interesting lead right now is a pair of URLs that both return the same plaintext message but with a time/date header on only one. Is there a way to determine if these are static pages, or if this is dynamic or queried data being pulled based on the URL? This server shows as nginx. The second URL is the 'same' as the first, in that it is a simple decimal to ascii conversion of the first.

https://crowscrowscrows.com/455559606264444855586263535557586253495156606349

please,

water

https://crowscrowscrows.com/EUY%60bdDHUXbcSUWXbSIQV%60cI

### created: Fri, 4 Aug 1995 07:59:51 GMT

please,

water

Comment: Hmm... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/August_in_the_Water

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to determine whether a page is static or dynamic based on the URL alone, because the server may be doing [URL rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine).